# nginx location directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, location, passenger

I have an nginx server with a rails app.
my nginx.conf is

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name nerto.it;
      root /var/www/current/public; 
      passenger_enabled on;


    location /m {
        passenger_enabled off;
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /m/index.html?q=$uri;
    }
...
}
```

It works except address like
nerto.it/mprove or nerto.it/mtry

where the initial letter is /m and nginx take this address like nerto.it/m

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /m/ {
    passenger_enabled off;
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /m/index.html?q=$uri;
}
```

or

```
location = /m {
    ...
}
```

It is unclear from your question what behaviour do you expect.

Please, read the documentation: http://nginx.org/r/location

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try smth like this:

```
location ~* ^/m(.*) {
```

> Regular expressions are specified by prepending them with the “~*” prefix (for case-insensitive matching), or with the “~” prefix (for case-sensitive matching).

[nginx location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)